# OK.RU embed videos set start time and hide controls

Tags: api, video, embed

I want to embed a video from **[Ok.ru](https://www.ok.ru)** and then specify the time on which the video should start (eg: the video should start from second 5), and to hide the controls, like on YouTube's embed API.

I just found their API, but I am unable to find how to do the above.

**[Ok.ru](https://www.ok.ru)** API is viewable here: **[English Documentation](https://apiok.ru/en/)**

How to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever seen an OK.ru link that shows such a start time or hides controls? In other words, you know for sure these features are possible with their system? Just because Youtube allows it does not mean other companies will do it also.

Comment: @VC.One most "companies" allows it... like DailyMotion, Youtube, Vimeo, SoundCloud (audio) etc.

Comment: Dailymotion and Vimeo are competing with Youtube so to keep customers happy they include its popular features. OK.ru seems more like a social network. Maybe if Facebook server videos allowed a specific start time then OK.ru will add such a feature.

Comment: @VC.One Thank you. So this feature is not available on `ok.ru`.

Comment: You can check with them by email : **api-support@ok.ru**

Comment: @VC.One thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents:

You can specify the start time by appending

?fromTime=...

to the URL, e.g.,

https://ok.ru/live/2001158479822?fromTime=38